# excel-formula sum over 1st character within a range in which 1st character is always an integer

Tags: excel-formula

I have a column of survey responses to a question in which the data is an integer 1 through 5 inclusive followed by text (e.g., "5 stars - I love it"). I want to sum the integers in the 1st characters. The dirty way would be to create a new column in which all but the first character is stripped, but I thought I'd be slick and avoid this.

However, my CSE array formula seems to be summing COUNTA(...) instead of summing over the LEFT(...,1) in the cells

```
{=SUM(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(AC$62:AC$9999,1)))}
```

I'm wondering why there's an implicit COUNTA included here and whether CSE formula is not a good way to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with data in **A1** through **A5**, use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--LEFT(A1:A5,1))
```

[image]

As you see, the formula discards everything after the leading digit.

**NOTE:**

If you replace blanks with zeros, the formula will work.

**EDIT#2:**

You can avoid the helper column if you use the **array formula**:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(IF(A1:A6="",0,A1:A6),1)))
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Gary's Student! I forgot to mention that the question is optional, so there are blank cells in the range as well. Your formula seems to work as long as there are no missing values. I'm going to experiment with ways to sum over only populated cells.

Comment: Thank you! My boss informed me that this is not possible without VBA or creating a hidden helper column (the "dirty" way I referenced above). I'm going with the latter because I'm garbage at VBA

Comment: @Charles  You CAN avoid the helper column...see my **EDIT#2**